# docker-compose: how to set active directory when building a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, path

I have a repository containing multiple small programs. This repository contains a `docker-compose.yml` file describing how to build and deploy them. Here is what it looks like:

```
root_dir/
├── api_endpoint/ # Rust-based API endpoint
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── Cargo.lock
│   ├── config.toml
│   └── ... # Other files and folders
├── docker-compose.yml # Deployment
└── ... # Other files and folders
```

in my `docker-compose.yml`, I describe how to setup api_endpoint this way, with a reference to its Dockerfile:

```yaml
  api_endpoint:
    container_name: api_endpoint
    build:
      context: ./api_endpoint/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ./target/release/api_endpoint
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Its Dockerfile describes how to build it within its repository (since it is a submodule, I don't want to reference itself from a parent directory, hence why I use 'context' in the docker-compose):

```
# Use the official Rust image as the base image
FROM rust:latest

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR .

RUN ls -la

# Copy the Cargo.toml and Cargo.lock files
COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock config.toml ./

# Copy the source code
COPY src ./src

# Build the application in release mode
RUN cargo build --release

# Expose the port your application uses (replace 8083 with your app's port)
EXPOSE 8080

# Set the unbuffered environment variable
ENV RUST_BACKTRACE "1"

# Run the binary
CMD ["./target/release/sales_manager"]
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I thought `context` would tell Docker to build following the Dockerfile instruction within the specified folder, but apparently it doesn't find the Cargo.toml and other required files:

```
 => ERROR [api_endpoint 3/6] COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock config.toml ./                                                                0.0s
------
 > [api_endpoint 3/6] COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock config.toml ./:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 8db5d66a-6f05-4912-8572-2314030d9bab::x99t9ep9g1ec5vv0ry36p4816: "/Cargo.lock": not found
```

What would be a proper way to fix that issue? I feel like changing the Dockerfile (which works with a docker-compose in the same folder) is not optimal but I probably didn't understand how to use context correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the errors, it seems the issue is related to the `COPY` commands in your `Dockerfile`.  The `COPY` command expects the source files to be relative to the build context, which is the `api_endpoint` directory in your case. Therefore, you would need to update the `COPY` command in your `Dockerfile` to use the correct relative paths:

```
# Copy the Cargo.toml and Cargo.lock files
COPY api_endpoint/Cargo.toml api_endpoint/Cargo.lock api_endpoint/config.toml ./

# Copy the source code
COPY api_endpoint/src ./src
```